# After Windows 10 Fall Creators Update recent used app will launch on startup

Tags: boot, window, windows-10-v1709

I just updated Windows 10 to Fall Creators Update and since then I have 'unwanted' behavior.

If I leave open Chrome or any application when shutting down the PC, next time I boot up the system Windows will open the same Chrome tab/page and application automatically. So it looks like there is an option somewhere to remember last open task and open then on startup?

Does anyone know where to find this option or where to disable this feature?

Comment: May the windows is going into sleep mode instead of shutting down.

Comment: Nope. 100% is shutting down.

Comment: The behavior you indicate is unwanted has been a feature of Windows 10 since it was released.  It actually is working has intended.

Comment: where can I disable this? I did not have this before the fall update

Comment: The thing does not even work properly. My PC restarted with many empty office apps (document not open) and empty Visual Studios (solutions not open).

Comment: How do I prevent Windows Update's restarts from using the new restart mode?

Answer (score 14):

**New Answer** (2020-10-22)

By now, there are dedicated settings allowing you to control this behavior.

Go to **Settings > Account > Sign-in options** and scroll down to the bottom. There will be two settings:

- "Automatically save my restartable apps when I sign out and restart them after I sign in." (new in Windows 10 2004)
- "Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device after an update or restart."

I recommend turning both **off**, despite only the first seemingly dealing with this feature. I still noticed some apps opening after a restart if I did not turn off both options.

[image]

The following, old answer workarounds this by using a script to shutdown:

---

**Old Answer**

Here's a silly workaround for the similarly silly new feature.

Some background first: Windows seems to shutdown as if `%WINDIR%\system32\shutdown.exe` was invoked with the `/sg /hybrid /t 0` parameters. The magic is in the `/sg` parameter which tells it to "restart any registered applications" on the next boot. The "old" `/s` parameter still exists and `shutdown` can be invoked with it manually.

To quickly call `shutdown.exe` like that, create a shortcut either in your apps list (`%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` for all users, `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` for the current user), or somewhere else and then pin it to start.

The important shortcut properties are the following:

- Name: `Shutdown`
- Target: `%WINDIR%\system32\shutdown.exe /s /hybrid /t 0`
- Start in: `%WINDIR%\system32`

Optional:

- Name: Add a non-breakable space (Alt+Num255) in front of it to appear at the top of the All Apps list. You can try other fancy Unicode characters if you like.
- Run: `Minimized` to prevent the ugly command prompt from popping up shortly.
- Icon: Change to something nice (there's an XP-style shutdown icon available in the default `shell32.dll`, or some close / critical icons in `imageres.dll`).
- Comment: Leave a rant here about the dumb new feature.

It can look like this in the end:

[image: The shutdown shortcut in action]

If you want a shortcut doing the same for restarting, the old `/r` switch can be used which was replaced by the new `/g` switch.

Comment: It works, great! This means if I start using this new icon to shut the PC down, instead of the regular one, the Falls Creator Update will *only* have caused my Bluetooth dongle to stop working (for the third time)... Yay! Thank you, Microsoft, for your forced updates policy, and for changing things without giving us a choice!

Comment: Jesus christ, this is so dumb. Microsoft have truly doubled down on the lunacy of forcing stupid "functionality" on their users, not because they asked for it but because Microsoft thinks it's the right way.

Comment: Good but one thing goes strange for me. While holding `Alt` and typing `255` from numpad, I get `ÿ` instead of an nbsp. How?

Comment: Different code page, try copying another whitespace character from the Wikipedia page about whitespaces.

Comment: Really screwed me. I work with dozens of Chrome tabs open and with Chrome set so as it opens last session. If I close Chrome I lose all my open tabs. I HATE THIS "FEATURE" (Oh and only started on my machine this morning - useless &^%$^&)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, this is the intended behavior recently added to Windows. A thread on the Microsoft Windows community forum about the issue can be found [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_desktop/programs-autostart-after-boot-in-windows-10/09dd8d3e-7b36-45d1-9181-6587dd5d53ab?page=2).

According to the thread there is currently no way to disable the "feature". The way to start without any apps reopening is (quote from a Microsoft Support Engineer):

> If you want to start with no apps open (other than those set to auto-start via Task Manager/Start), you'll need to ensure all apps are closed before shutting down or restarting the PC.

---

However, according to this [link](http://windowsreport.com/restore-apps-pc-reboot/), it should be possible to turn on and off.

> To activate this feature, go to Settings > Accounts > Sign-in > (under Privacy) “Use my sign info to automatically finish setting up”.

You can try turning it off this option.

Comment: What baffles me is that I have "Use my sign info to automatically finish setting up" activated and I never ever encountered this feature, even though I sometimes intentionally leave my browser open when shutting down (so restoring the session is easier). What baffles me even more is that I also did not even encounter this feature when I had “Use my sign info to automatically finish setting up” deactivated. *Not that I miss it**, but I still think that this is weird.

Comment: Toggling “Use my sign info to automatically finish setting up” does not disable this (unwanted for me) behaviour. Still looking for a way to boot without windows automatically restoring previously open applications

Comment: Don't think this link is relevant. It is for when Windows Update runs. Made bugger all difference to this ghastly new "feature". Just when I thought MS were getting a bit better.